# Attribute "page" must be declared for element type "definition"

Tags: java, tiles

I'm trying to build a Tiles project , but I'm facing error in  the WEB-INF folder

more specifically in the tiles-defs-infra.xml

the error is :

> Attribute "page" must be declared for element type "definition".

```
<definition name="infrastructure.layout.default" page="/WEB-INF/pages/infrastructure/layout-index.jsp">
```

The header of the page is like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration//EN"
"http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/tiles-config.dtd">
```

I don't understand what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read here  [/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml](https://tiles.apache.org/2.2/framework/tutorial/basic/pages.html) concerning how to create a definition , there is no such an attribute called "page"

Try replacing it with **layout** and it should work

Comment: Thank you , changing it to layout has solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the following

Instead of this :

```
definition name="infrastructure.layout.default" page="/WEB-INF/pages/infrastructure/layout-index.jsp">
```

Do the following :

```
 definition name="infrastructure.layout.default" template="/WEB-INF/pages/infrastructure/layout-index.jsp">
```